# How does the NASA InSight lander determine the depth of a Marsquake?

Tags: planets, geophysics, nasa

With only one lander with this type of equipment at one location, how can the InSight lander's investigators be so sure of the depth of the Marsquakes it detects?

Comment: Do you mean this experiment?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_Experiment_for_Interior_Structure